# Compiling program that requires python 2.6

Tags: python, software-installation

I'm trying to compile a software package but it fails with

```
g++ -Wall -O0 -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include/python2.5  -g -pthread -fpic  -I../../plot/src -I../../math/src -I../../rclib/src/util -I../../rclib/src/conui -I../../rclib/src/io -I../../_general -I../../clop/src -I../../clop/src/real -I../../clop/src/artificial -I../../clop/src/math -DPTHREADS -DGUI=nogui -Drestrict=__restrict__ -DKBHIT_UNIX -DCLOCK_FTIME -c -o ../swig/clop_swig_wrap.o ../swig/clop_swig_wrap.cxx
../swig/clop_swig_wrap.cxx:149:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../swig/clop_swig_wrap.o] Error 1
```

Since Python 2.6 is no longer available in synaptic, I downloaded, built, and installed it from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.8/ , but it didn't add the 2.6 libraries to /usr/include

How do I get the python2.6 libraries into /usr/include on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Where did it put the libs? You can almost certainly copy them to /usr/include (or re-write the source code with the proper path in -I ...)

Comment: If it is not in /usr/include/python2.6 i think you don not have installed it probably. the commands are `./configure`, `make` and than `sudo make install`.

Comment: I don't know.  I just ran sudo apt-get install so it put them wherever it put them (but not in /usr/include/python2.6 where I need it to put them)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
sudo make install
```

installs python header files to /usr/local/include/python2.6, but CLOP was searching for the files in /usr/include/python2.6

I copied them over and there was no more trouble

Answer (score 1):

1. First download the [source code](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.8/).
2. Open up a terminal and cd to your download dir `cd Downloads` (or just Dow and tab ;)).
3. `tar -xvf Python-2.6.8.tar.bz2`
4. `cd Python-2.6.8.tar.bz2`
5. `./configure` (and check if everything is configured correctly)
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`
8. `sudo cp -r /usr/local/include/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.6` and for solving your problem ;)

And you are done ;).

EDIT: /usr/local/include/python2.6 contains pyconfig.h whereas ./Include does not

Comment: Why copying over files if you can change the search path in your compiler options? It's meant to search in `/usr/local` paths if this is not a package installation. Please don't make this a habit.