# How do I get python2.7 back to the command "python"?

Tags: command-line, python

When i do the command `python` i get the folowing.

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Apr  9 2013, 19:12:12) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I want to have python2.7 back to that command. so i have this:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have already tried to change the symlink in `/usr/bin/python` but don't work :(. I am also afraid that some programs will break.

Comment: How did you get the 2.6.8 version?

Comment: Becouse i was solving this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/279630/compiling-program-that-requires-python-2-6/279644#279644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, sorry I couldn't work out what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo update-alternatives --config python`

Comment: Don't work get error: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python`

Comment: Odd... how did the symlink "not work" by the way, because that's definitely the obvious way of doing it.

Comment: `which python` to make sure he didn't mangle up his path in .profile or .bash_rc

Comment: The output of `which python` is `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: In that case change the symlink for /usr/local/bin/python and /usr/bin/python, to be on the safe side.

Comment: The problem is that `/usr/local/bin/` contains data of python 2.6.

Comment: I thought /usr/local/bin would only contain symlinks to binaries, which use the correct data found in /usr/local/lib/program-versionnumber

Comment: Oke i will try it ;)